# LongPress on iPhone app opens 3 Alerts? AlertView or Gesture Code Issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer, uialertview

In my iPhone app I have set a long press to show an alert box, When I do the long press in testing it opens the alert but then I have to click "OK" 3 times before it goes away. It's almsot like it's opened 3 long press alert windows instead of just one.

What am I doing wrong?  Here is the code I am using to handle the long press:

```
- (void)didLongPress_imageButton3:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
  UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
  alertView.title = @"The Info";
  alertView.message = @"Details of what is in the project.";
  [alertView addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
  [alertView show];
  [alertView release];
}
```

Comment: Try to put NSLog and check how many times your method is getting called. Comment out Alert code and debug. Seems your method is executed many times.

Comment: Read about recognizer states.